# Minecraft Scoreboard stat.mineBlock won't work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I wanted to set up something that uses `stat.mineBlock.snow`, but it wouldn't work. I tried other `stat.mineBlock`, but they wouldn't work either. I did the command `/scoreboard objectives add snow stat.mineBlock.snow Snow` But it returns with `Usage: Invalid objective criteria type 'stat.mineBlock.snow'`
So what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I see the bigger problem. I've had trouble with other things that have to do with the new name system. I did the new objective but only with the snow ID, and it worked. So, for some reason I can't use the names in commands for some unknown reason. Should I start a new question for this?

Answer (score 4):

Even though it seems you got it working by using the numerical ID, there is a way to add it by using the friendly names. instead of `stat.mineBlock.snow`, it would have to be `stat.mineBlock.minecraft.snow`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put criteria.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria

```
/scoreboard objectives add stat.mineBlock.snow (Criteria)
```

Comment: This is incorrect; the OP's syntax was in the correct order. On the same page linked is the syntax: `/scoreboard objectives add <name> <criteria> [display name...]`, in which the criteria comes after the name. The name the OP specified is "snow" with the criteria being "stat.mineBlock.snow". The issue was an invalid criteria name due to the missing prefix "minecraft", as explained in the other answer.